# Waiting for data in an Angular Interceptor using an RxJs BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to rxjs - I sort of understand most of the operators, but I don't understand a particular use of `BehaviorSubject`, `filter`, and `take`.

I want to renew an oauth access and refresh token pair, in an Angular interceptor. All the code I've seen here and in blogs are the same - there seems to be a standard way to do it. But there is one bit that I don't understand.

As [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54148818/9971404), this part queues requests until new access and refresh tokens are available.

```
private refreshSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

// ...etc.

if (!this.refreshInProgress) {
  // request new access and refresh tokens from server
  // populate refreshSubject once tokens received
}
else {
  return this.refreshSubject.pipe(
    filter(result => result !== null),                      // <---- ???
    take(1),                                                // <---- ???
    switchMap(() => next.handle(this.addToken(request)))
  );
}
```

All such examples explain that requests are queued until `refreshSubject` is populated with the new tokens, and that the magic happens in `filter`.

This is what I don't understand. The [rxjs docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter) do not say that `filter` causes waiting - where/how does the wait and queuing occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the initial value of the BehaviorSubject is "NULL" (before the request or socket connection to get the new token is made) you need to pick the values that are different from NULL, in order to do this we use the "[filter](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter)" operator

```
filter(result => result !== null),
```

This will emit only the values that are different from NULL into the next pipeline step of the BehaviorSubject.

Now we have to only "take" **one** of the emitted values from the BehaviorSubject (You must need this because of the way that youre getting the new token), in order to do this we use the "[take](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take)" operator.

```
take(1),
```

This will only emit **ONE** value, even if there were 10 emitted values, only the first one will be piped into the next pipeline step.

After all that you handle the values with the "switchMap", but remember that the BehaviorSubject emits the the current value (the last value emitted) every time it gets a new subscription.

Comment: Thanks! I do however understand all this. The question is how are requests queued until the tokens are available. I thought `take` terminates the stream, so how does queuing occur?

Comment: Well in the example that you shared, theres no queuing, only the BehaviorSubject that is always emitting the last token that the server sent, too understand the actual "queuing" i need to see more of the code and how youre using the BehaviorSubject to "queue" the requests for the tokens.

Comment: Okay that is what I thought, there is no queueing. The code comes from the example I linked to. Every example like that says there is queueing, but I didn't believe it. Thanks for confirming for me!

Comment: I spent a lot more time on this and I think I see my confusion now - you are right there isn't "queuing", but there is "waiting". All failed requests that need a new refreshed token are subscribed to the interceptor's observable, so they are in effect, "waiting". Once the new token is available, that stream is completed and all those requests can be retried with the new tokens. So actually they were "waiting" all along but not because a queue was used, rather just because they were waiting for an observable/subscription to complete. Does that make sense?

Comment: LOL this was a learning experience - the real problem is the docs for `take`: ["An Observable that emits only the first count values emitted by the source Observable, or all of the values from the source if the source emits fewer than count values."](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take). So I thought if there are zero values then `take(1)` would just complete immediately - but that isn't true!! What actually happens is it will **WAIT** until there is at least one value, then complete! :-) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Haha its nice to know i can help ;)